# java : anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

In java this is valid

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
    {   
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                System.out.println("From anonymous:"+i);
        }
    }   
).start();
```

But this is not :

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable()
    {   
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                System.out.println("From anonymous:"+i);
        }
    }   
).start();
```

can I achieve it with anonymous class? If yes then How

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly? `start` method just runs the thread. And `run` method does not return any value.

Comment: I want to call **start** method with object creation.

Answer (score 8):

Your code does not work, because it wants to assign the result of the `start()` method to the variable `t`. You can do it like so:

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable()
    {   
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                System.out.println("From anonymous:"+i);
        }
    }   
);
t.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, in this case you don't need to use Runnable interface because is implemented by the Thread class.

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
               System.out.println("From anonymous:"+i);
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note here is that the [start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) method of Thread returns void. This is why you cannot assign it to a variable.